# Me da fallos en el metodo comienza_barra() desde un host remoto

Tags: javascript, html5, host

Expongo mi script. Concreatamente me da fallo en el metodo `comienza_barra()`. Me lo da el depurador. Lo ejecuto desde un host remoto y no hace nada.

```
function comenzar(){
 zonadatos=document.getElementById("zonadatos");
    zonaprogreso=document.getElementById("zonaprogreso");
    var boton=document.getElementById("boton");

    boton.addEventListener("click", leer, false);//Poner boton a la escucha
}

function leer(){//Creamos metodo para leer la url

    var url="doc.pdf";
    var solicitud= new XMLHttpRequest();//Creamos objeto de tipo XMLHttpRequest

    solicitud.addEventListener("loadstart", comienza_barra, false);
    solicitud.addEventListener("progress", estado_barra, false);
    solicitud.addEventListener("load", mostrar, false);//Ponemos objeto a la escucha
    solicitud.open("GET", url, true);//Abrir el archivo
    solicitud.send(null);//Enviar informacion
}

function comienza_barra(){

    zonadatos.innerHTML=<progress value='0' max='100'></progress>;
}

function estado_barra(e){   

    var porcentaje=parseInt(e.loaded/e.total*100);//Regla de 3
    var barraprogreso=zonadatos.querySelector("progress");//Identificar nuestra barra de progreso

    barraprogreso.value=porcentaje;//Almacenamos el valor de la barra en porcentaje
    zonaprogreso.innerHTML=porcentaje + " %";
}

function mostrar(e){

    zonadatos.innerHTML="Archivo leido!!";//Nos den lo pedido en formato texto
}

window.addEventListener("load", comenzar, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola Miguelo a primera vista el error que se ve es que el `innerHTML` acepta `string(cadenas)` por lo que seria de la siguiente manera:

```
zonadatos.innerHTML = "<progress value='0' max='100'></progress>";
```

Comment: Gracias. Me compilo bien